# Image compression using a docker pngquant

Tags: docker, pngquant

It is necessary to compress a lot of pictures. For this I use the pngquant to sort through every picture, compress and overwrite it.
As a result, after each search I receive the following message: "cannot open for reading"

Where did I make a mistake?

```
time find . -type f -name \*.png -exec docker run --rm -v "$(pwd)" pngquant *.png --ext -f {} \;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ComVS.jpg)

Comment: So you want to run a docker image for each and every PNG file and in there you want to run `pngquant` on all your PNG files?

Comment: Yes, every png file need compress.

Comment: So if you have 4,000 PNG files you want to run `docker` 4,000 times? And each time you run it, you want to `pngquant` 4,000 images?

Comment: I do not see other options. If I run the compressor without going through each image, the docker will complain about a large list of arguments.